# How can i refer one property file from another property file in spring cloud config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have to implement spring cloud config for an existing project where i have an use case to handle
Here Some property files are referred by other property files like 
logging.propFile=classpath:/cfg/xyz.properties and these property files are used in multiple places like

Properties property = new Properties();
property.load(new FileInputStream(propsPath));
logger = somefactory.createfactory(property.get("logging.propFile")); and this factory creation is defined in a different jar.

If i move all property files in git repo files i mentioned will not be available in class path and if i go for code change a lot of code change is involved.What is the best way to handle this situation.
Is there any way to refer one property file to another in spring cloud config .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Config server allows for reading static files through HTTP. So you can put your references properties file into the configuration git repository and reference them through `http://<configserver_url>/*/*/<branch_name>/xyz.properties`. This only works when your code can handle URLs, so the `FileInputStream` in your example would not do it.

See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_alternative_formats.html and https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html.

Also note the `resolvePlaceholders` query parameter that defaults to `true`.

We are using this for keeping our logback.xml configuration in the config server by setting `logging.config: http://<configserver_url/*/*/master/logback.xml?resolvePlaceholders=false`